# Comparison in twig templates

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, entities

I have a list field for a custom content type that looks like this:

Field **Machine name** is: `field_app_os`

```
key|label
Win|Windows
Android|Android
```

I can access the `key` in Twig template by using `content.field_app_os` or [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) and the output of both is `Android`:

> Twig Field Value allows Drupal 8 themers to get partial data from
>   field render arrays. It gives them more control over the output
>   without drilling deep into the render array or using preprocess
>   functions.
>   Filters:
>   - field_label : Returns the field label value.
>   - field_value : Returns the render array of the field value(s) without the field wrappers.

```
/* with use of Twig Field Value module */
{{ content.field_app_os|field_value }}  {# outputs 'Android' #}

 /* without use of Twig Field Value module */
{{ content.field_app_os }}  {# outputs 'Android' #}
```

However, if I do a simple comparison, the output of both is False.

```
{% set app_os = content.field_app_os|field_value %}
{{ kint(app_os == 'Android') }} {# outputs 'bool FALSE' #}
```

Or When I use:

```
{% set app_os = content.field_app_os %}
{{ kint(app_os == 'Android') }} {# outputs 'bool FALSE' #}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: What is the output when you do {% set app_os = content.field_app_os|field_value %} {% if app_os == 'Android' %} app_os is Android{% endif %} ?

Comment: Hmm weird. I wonder if 'content.field_app_os|field_value' is slightly different. Like maybe there's white space or something. As a test what happens if you just straight do {% set app_os = 'Android' %} does it work then?

Comment: Okay well At least we got it down to 'content.field_app_os|field_value' being the issue. And you are completely positive it's producing just that string with nothing else? And it doesn't produce that string inside an array or anything like that?

Comment: Here's a chat room we can discuss this in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66357/mojtaba-reyhani-and-matt-chat

Comment: For those who are attempting to resolve the issue: As a test  
{{ content.field_app_os }} produced 'Android' but {% if content.field_app_os == 'Android' %} True {% endif %} didn't work.

Comment: The question is, when using a key/label pair, why not use the key for logic, which you get in `node.field_app_os.value`? Otherwise your logic breaks if you translate the label. And the fields in content contain render arrays, so you can't compare it to a string.

Comment: @4k4: Thanks for your help and attention, When I use `node.field_app_os.value` then all things work correctly, But can you explain a little more about the cause of this issue, Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{{ content }} is a render array, where you find the label of the key/label pair probably here:

```
{{ content.field_app_os[0]['#markup'] }}
```

But this is not ideal for logic:

1. The position in the render array can change, for example if you
   install a layout module.
2. The content of #markup depends on how the
   field formatter is configured in the view mode.
3. The label is translatable, so the
   logic breaks on a multilingual site.

So it's better to use the database value in:

```
{{ node.field_app_os.value }}
```

This is the first part of the key/label pair, which is untranslatable and you can access the value independent on how the field is configured in the view mode.

Comment: Thank you so much, But for what when I use [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value), The `{{ content.field_app_os|field_value }}` not work correctly?

Comment: I don't know this module, but this is probably to extract the part of the render array which renders the value without the field div's and not to extract a string value you can use in a logic expression. In general use `content.` for rendering and `node.` for logic.